# Incorrect redirect on .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to have pretty urls in my website, and I coded a .htaccess file. Nevertheless, when I try to access the second rule, it redirects to the first one. Other rules work fine. I tried the target url and works perfect, and tested the code with online tool and matches perfectly the rule. So, what Im doing wrong?

Here my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule piscinas index.php?seccion=piscinas
RewriteRule natatorios index.php?seccion=natatorios
RewriteRule bordes-atermicos index.php?seccion=bordes
RewriteRule reservorios-industriales index.php?seccion=reservorios
RewriteRule reservorios index.php?seccion=reservorios
RewriteRule tanques-australianos index.php?seccion=reservorios
RewriteRule aguadas index.php?seccion=aguadas
```

With that code, when I go to myurl.com/natatorios it redirects me to index.php?seccion=piscinas instead of index.php?seccion=natatorios

Comment: I do not see a reason for the behavior you describe. It is more likely that you have an issue inside the php based logic...

Comment: Apart from that you should alter your rules... Instead of (for example) `RewriteRule piscinas index.php?seccion=piscinas` use `RewriteRule ^/?piscinas$ /index.php?seccion=piscinas [L]`.